# I want to put an image on top of carousel in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want half of my dp to be on top of the carousel image and it should be in center. The carousel should be like a cover page as in facebook.

```css
.dp-container{
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin-top: -100px;
        padding: 1px;
        z-index: 1000;
        background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
      }
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide lessz" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="carousel1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" height="400">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="carousel2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" height="400">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="carousel3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" height="400">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
        <img src="mydp.jpg" class="dp-container container">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to parent.

```
    .carousel-inner{
       position:relative;
     }
```

And then `position:absolute;` to img and place it at the bottom.

```css
 .carousel-inner{
       position:relative;
  }
.dp-container{
        position:absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 1px;
        z-index: 1000;
        background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
        left:400px;
        bottom:20px;
      }
```

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide lessz" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="carousel1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" height="400">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="carousel2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" height="400">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="carousel3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" height="400">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
        <img src="mydp.jpg" class="dp-container container"/>
```